# Ubuntu stuck with old monitor's max resolution?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution, monitor

I was using 1280x768 and it looked blurry. So I went to Displays and tried to change to the maximum resolution: 1366x768. But it threw a limit error. Only then I realized that was my old monitors resolution. How can I do it to use the maximum resolution of the current monitor and not the old one? This is what I see if I run `xrandr`:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 768, maximum 1366 x 1366
LVDS connected 1280x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x768       60.0* 
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1024x600       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   800x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT1 connected 1280x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0 +   76.0     75.0     72.0  
   1280x960       76.0     75.0     72.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0     60.0  
   1280x768       76.0     75.0*    72.0     60.0  
   1280x720       76.0     75.0     72.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   1024x600       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   800x480        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     67.0     59.9  
   640x350        60.0     70.1  
alex@alex-K43U:~$
```

(My laptop's monitor is broken so I'm using an external mirror monitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your output, your current resolution is 1280x768. The highest monitor supports is 1280x1024.

> CRT1 connected 1280x768

Other supported settings:

> 1280x1024      60.0 +   76.0     75.0     72.0
>   1280x960       76.0     75.0     72.0     60.0
>   1152x864       75.0     60.0
>   1280x768       76.0     75.0*    72.0     60.0
>   1280x720       76.0     75.0     72.0     60.0
>   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0
>   1024x600       75.0     70.1     60.0
>   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2
>   800x480        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2
>   640x480        75.0     72.8     67.0     59.9
>   640x350        60.0     70.1

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely your graphics card, depending on the age of your computer the graphics card cannot handle such resolution, or it could just be your monitor, if it is a CRT monitor (a fat square one) then that's most likely the problem, because those types of monitors cannot handle 16:9 ratio resolutions only 4:3 resolutions.

Edit: The screen connection is probably the problem since you have broken it, the connection might just wont take any of the data sent to it.

Comment: As you can see in the log output it is a CRT monitor and OP is trying to use a resolution not supported. Highest his/hers allows is 1280x1024,currently its at 1280x768

Comment: I can see that, but he/she is trying to change his laptop's screen resolution, so could be, as stated above, that the connection is faulty.